# The caption of MS excel table in MS Word is diappeared when I update the whole file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, updates, caption

I have inseted a table of MS Excel in MS Word and then I inserted an caption in it. The problem is that when I update the file as  a whole (Ctrl+A -> right click -> update field) the caption is diappeared. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pasted the table as (link and keep source formatting) from paste options. The correct option is Keep source formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try locking the anchor of the caption which should still allow you to move the caption if needed but should prevent it from disappearing.

To lock the anchor of a caption `right-click` and selct `More Layout Options...` then ensure you are on the `Position` tab and tick the `Lock anchor` box as highlighted in the image link below for reference.

[Caption Layout options.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU9qV.jpg)